# Proof checking and understanding whether continuity of $f''(x)$ was needed at all or not

Tags: calculus

Let $f: R \rightarrow R$ be twice continuously
differentiable (or $f''$ exists and is continuous) such that $f(0)=f(1)=f^{\prime}(0)=0$. Then

- $f^{\prime \prime}(c)=0$ for some $c \in R$
- there is no point for which $f^{\prime \prime}(x)=0$
- at all points $f^{\prime \prime}(x)>0$
- at all points $f^{\prime \prime}(x)<0$.

---

My method was as $f(0)$ and $f(1)$ have same value by Rolle's Theorem we can say that there is $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c$ in $(0,1)$ now also given that $f'(0) = 0$ , so now applying Rolle's in $f'(x)$ for $z$ belonging to $(0,c)$ we have $f''(z) = 0$, is it correct ? As such continuity of $f''(x)$ was never used, was it necessary?

Comment: You are right. Continuity of $f''$ is not needed.

Comment: Ok thanks @KaviRamaMurthy